Do the following steps I take work as intended to find the answer to the first function?
Sorry if this is hard to follow, but I'm not sure how else I can show what I tried to do.








therefore
$$ f\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{m}\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{n^{k}\sum_{p=0}^{k}\frac{k!\ln\left(2\right)^{\left(k-p\right)}\sum_{q=0}^{m}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{q}\cdot x^{\left(k+1\right)}\cdot\ln\left(x\right)^{\left(n+p-q\right)}\left(n+p\right)!}{\left(k+1\right)^{\left(q+1\right)}\left(n+p-q\right)!}}{p!\left(k-p\right)!}}{k!}}{n!} $$
Is equal to
$$
\int_{0}^{x}t^{\left(2t\right)^{t}}dt
$$
